# Adding HTML DOM template

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, underscore.js

I'm new to JS and jQuery. I wrote this function which just does what I want, but it seems very unreadable, and because of my experience, I don't know a better way to handle it.

Could you please give advise me how to refactor it?

```
function new_section(id, name, order) {

    return $('<tbody>')
        .attr('id', 'section_' + id)
        .attr('data-id', id)
        .attr('data-order', order)
        .append($('<tr>')
            .addClass('head-row')
            .attr('id', 'section_' + id + '_head_row')
            .append($('<td>')
                .attr('id', 'section_' + id + '_name_cell')
                .attr('colspan', window.row_length)
                .text(name)
                .addClass('bg-info')

                .append($('<a>').addClass('edit-section').attr('href', '#')
                    .append($('<i>').addClass('fa fa-pencil text-muted')))

                .append($('<span>').addClass('pipe-edit-section text-muted').text('|'))

                .append($('<a>').addClass('section-up').attr('href', '#')
                    .append($('<i>').addClass('fa fa-chevron-up text-muted')))

                .append($('<a>').addClass('section-down').attr('href', '#')
                    .append($('<i>').addClass('fa fa-chevron-down text-muted')))

                .append($('<span>').addClass('pipe-edit-section text-muted').text('|'))

                 .append($('<a>').addClass('delete-section').attr('href', '#')
                    .append($('<i>').addClass('fa fa-times-circle text-muted')))

        )
    );
}
```

**UPD:**

Found underscore templates. What do you think about this approach:

```
section = _.template([
            '<tbody id="section_<%= id %>" data-id="<%= id %>" data-order="<%= order %>">',
                '<tr id="section_<%= id %>_head_row" class="head-row">',
                    '<td id="section_<%= id %>_name_cell" class="bg-info" colspan="<%= row_length %>">',
                        '<%= name %>',
                        '<a href="#" class="edit-section">',
                            '<i class="fa fa-pencil text-muted"></i>',
                        '</a>',
                        '<span class="pipe-edit-section text-muted">|</span>',
                        '<a href="#" class="section-up">',
                            '<i class="fa fa-chevron-up text-muted"></i>',
                        '</a>',
                        '<a href="#" class="section-down">',
                            '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down text-muted"></i>',
                        '</a>',
                        '<span class="pipe-edit-section text-muted">|</span>',
                        '<a href="#" class="delete-section">',
                            '<i class="fa fa-times-circle text-muted"></i>',
                        '</a>',
                    '</td>',
            '</tbody>'].join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to refactor here and you already identified the problem scope.

You are much better off with a [JavaScript template engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).

I won't be too opinionated here, but popular options are:

- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/
- http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template
- http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/